# Cannot find ContentPlaceHolder 'TitleContent' in the master page 'X/Site.Master' happening on one server but not another

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I'm getting this annoying error in one environment but not another and I can't explain it. I don't have a TitleContent in the master page or in the content page.

So how can this be occurring and more importantly, how can I stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry all. I found it

There is another error occurring (which is not being logged) that makes it show the Error.aspx page. This page does refer to the TitleContent placeholder.

Now to just find the other issue ...

Cheers